# Setting up p4 client with a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, vim, perforce

I'm trying to use a bash script to set up command line Perforce after running a Chef cookbook that installs Perforce. My client name is 'test_project'. After I attempt a p4 sync, I get the following error:

```
Client 'test_project' unknown - use 'client' command to create it.
```

I see that I can run `p4 client test_project` manually, which opens vim and creates the client. All I need to do is quit the file, and the client is set up. But I don't know how to handle that in a bash script.

How do I exit vim in a bash script? Or how else do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a variation on gareth_bowles answer:

> p4 client -o test_project | p4 client -i

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get around this is to use the -i flag to read in a client spec from a file:

```
cat clientspec.txt | p4 client -i
```

Just change your cookbook to install the client spec file and optionally make any needed edits to it.